# Is there a measure invariant with respect to the Möbius transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, mobius-transformation

I would like to use a measure ${\rm d} \mu (z)$ on ${\mathbb C}$ so that for any  $f(z)$ $$\int_{\mathbb C} f(z) {\rm d} \mu (z)$$ is invariant under Möbius transformations.

Taking the transformation as $$M(z) = \frac{a z + b}{cz + d}$$ the measure also might be invariant only under the special Möbius transformations with $ad - bc = 1$. Does such a measure exist?

Comment: As explained by Willie Wong, there is no such measure, but there may still be a quasi-invariant measure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-invariant_measure

Comment: There's actually another subtlety to the problem that the current answer does not address: the Mobius transformations are not $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ but $\bar{\mathbb{C}} \to\bar{\mathbb{C}}$. From this point of view the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{S}^2$ gives a quasi-invariant measure as your suggested, since $M:\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ are diffeomorphisms. @JohnvonN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The Mobius transformations include as special cases scalings and translations. Consider now the square $[-1,1) \times [-1,1)$. If $\mu$ is invariant under the Mobius transformations we must have

$$ \mu([-1,1)\times [-1,1)) = \mu([0,1)\times[0,1)) $$

while

$$ \mu([-1,1)\times [-1,1)) = \mu([0,1)\times[0,1)) + \mu([0,1)\times[-1,0)) + \mu([-1,0)\times[0,1)) + \mu([-1,0)\times[-1,0)) = 4 \mu([0,1)\times[0,1)) $$

implying $\mu([-1,1)\times [-1,1)) = 0$. The same argument shows if any open bounded set $A$ is measurable, it would have measure $\mu(A) = 0$.

Thus by sigma-sub-additivity you have that $\mu$ can only be the zero measure if there exists some open $A$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$.

On the other hand, the [counting measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) is invariant under Mobius transformations.

Comment: But what about non-canonical $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{C}$? I was thinking about choosing an arbitrary point $z_0$ and integrating $f(M_{abcd}(z_0))$ with [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) over $a,b,c,d$. This should be invariant but the parameters are degenerate so the definition of the integral would have to be rather special.

Comment: @Void: the Mobius group $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is not compact; its "Haar measure" would have infinite total content and you end up with the "infinity everywhere situation" that the answerer mentioned. Note for example that the Lebesgue measure is not actually formed from integrating the "Haar measure" over the Euclidean symmetries.