# Do Mobius transformations preserve Hausdorff dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, hausdorff-measure

***Do Mobius transformations preserve Hausdorff dimension?***

This may be related to: [Is there a measure invariant with respect to the Möbius transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259315/is-there-a-measure-invariant-with-respect-to-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformation)

I believe the answer is yes, but I want some intuition behind it, and eventually, a proof.

Since a Mobius transformation is a combination of translations, dilations, rotations, and inversions, it suffices to show that each of these mappings preserves the Hausdorff dimension.

*Motivation:*

This image

[image: Curvilinear triangle packing]

and this image

[image: strip packing]

are the same (up to an inversion/Mobius transformation). In both images, the "dust" or "residual set" left between the tangent circles has the same Hausdorff dimension $ \delta \approx 1.30568$.

Comment: I guess the answer is *yes*. Hausdorff dimension is preserved by any bi-Lipschitz map and the inversion $1/z$ is bi-Lipschitz on any annulus bounded away from $\infty$ and the origin because it's derivative is bounded there. By taking a countable union of such annuli, inversion preserves Hausdorff dimension on the punctured plane. I suppose that one extra point doesn't change things.